What is the difference between Hawking radiation and a black hole laser?
While reading this paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.6550), I got a little bit puzzled: what is the difference between Hawking radiation and a black hole laser? Is it the same thing? From my understanding, is black hole laser just an amplified Hawking radiation?
Can it be thought like this: if sunlight is analogous to Hawking radiation with randomly emitted particles, then the optical laser is analogous to the black hole laser?

There is no “black hole laser”. In this paper the authors describe an unrelated electromagnetic effect that they believe to be conceptually similar (“analogous”) to a gravitational black hole. They use a laser to amplify the radiation in their setup that they believe to be “analogous” to the Hawking radiation. Perhaps it is with pointing out their deliberately improper English: “an analog black hole” should be “an analog of a black hole” while “We observe Hawking radiation emitted by the black hole” is false since there is no black hole or Hawking radiation in their setup.
